# ClearML multiple tasks in single script changes logged value names

Tags: devops, clearml, trains

I trained multiple models with different configuration for a custom hyperparameter search. I use pytorch_lightning and its logging (TensorboardLogger).
When running my training script after Task.init() ClearML auto-creates a Task and connects the logger output to the server.

I log for each straining stage `train`, `val` and `test` the following scalars at each epoch: `loss`, `acc` and `iou`

When I have multiple configuration, e.g. `networkA` and `networkB` the first training log its values to `loss`, `acc` and `iou`, but the second to `networkB:loss`, `networkB:acc` and `networkB:iou`. This makes values umcomparable.

My training loop with Task initalization looks like this:

```
names = ['networkA', networkB']
for name in names:
     task = Task.init(project_name="NetworkProject", task_name=name)
     pl_train(name)
     task.close()
```

method pl_train is a wrapper for whole training with Pytorch Ligtning. No ClearML code is inside this method.

Do you have any hint, how to properly use the usage of a loop in a script using completly separated tasks?

---

Edit: ClearML version was 0.17.4. Issue is fixed in main branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer I'm part of the ClearML (formerly Trains) team.

`pytorch_lightning` is creating a new Tensorboard for each experiment. When ClearML logs the TB scalars, and it captures the same scalar being re-sent again, it adds a prefix so if you are reporting the same metric it will not overwrite the previous one. A good example would be reporting `loss` scalar in the training phase vs validation phase (producing "loss" and "validation:loss"). It might be the `task.close()` call does not clear the previous logs, so it "thinks" this is the same experiment, hence adding the prefix `networkB` to the `loss`. As long as you are closing the Task after training is completed you should have all experiments log with the same metric/variant (title/series). I suggest opening a GitHub issue, this should probably be considered a bug.

Comment: thanks for your ideas. I opened an issue: https://github.com/allegroai/clearml/issues/312

Comment: issue was fixed in the main branch. so just get a  version >= 0.17.5 (main branch or upcoming releases)